# One cannot place the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 to make the sum of the numbers on the hexagon equal to 7 times the number in the center.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-mathematics

**Question**

Prove by contradiction the following statement:

One cannot place the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 to make the sum of the numbers on the hexagon equal to 7 times the number in the center.

[image: Image of hexagon]

Let a, b, c, d, e, f be the numbers on the hexagon, and g the number in the center.

Write down an equation that corresponds to the negation of the statement, then try to reach a contradiction.

Note: This statement can be easily proved by explicitly trying all possible values for g. Such proof is not going to get credit.

**What I did**

I am confused on the equation that this is asking for. I think it would have been possible with brute force, though it is not allowed in the question. Does it mean x=7p where x is the sum of the outside corners and p the number in the middle?

Comment: The equation they have in mind is $a+b+c+d+e+f = 7g$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note $1+2+\cdots+7=28$. Let $x$ be the number in the middle, then $$28-x=7x$$ but it has no integer solution.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, $x=7p$ is the equation they want — if you substitute $x$ with $a+b+c+d+e+f$ and $p$ with $g$, that is.

As for proving the claim, note that for it to be true, $a+b+c+d+e+f\equiv 0\mod(7)$. Consider the sum of numbers from $1$ to $7$, which is $28$. Subtracting from this any number from $1$ to $7$ corresponds to a particular choice for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$. Since $28$ is itself a multiple of $7$, it is clear that subtracting any number from $1$ to $6$ will result in a number *not* divisible by $7$, so the only possible choice for the centre number is $7$ itself. But then the sum from $1$ to $6$ is $21$, which is certainly not equal to $7\times 7$, proving the claim.

Comment: No need to be so complicated.  $a+b+c+d+e+f = 7g$ but $a+b+c+d+e+f$ is the sum of all then numbers except $g$ so $a+b+c+d+e+f = 28 -g$ so we have $28-g=7g$.  (Or we could have added $g$ to both sides to get $a+b+c+d+e+f+g = 7g+g$ or $28 =8g$ and $g = 3\frac 12$.